# Volume manager tries to mount device while reformatting in gparted

Tags: mount, xfce, usb-drive, parted

When reformatting a USB drive with `gparted`, my volume manager attempts to mount the device. This results in some error messages telling me the device could not be mounted. The only way I know to turn these messages off, is to temporarily disable the auto-mount options in "Removable drives and media" settings for XFce4. Changing these settings constantly gets to be troublesome. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have [fixed a similar problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal/+bug/37768) for Gnome in Ubuntu.

The fix was in gparted, so maybe it can work for Xfce too.